# Closed form of $\lim_{n\to\infty}[(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n\ln(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2})})-\frac{{n \pi}^2}{6}]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

While working on [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511946/expanding-limit-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1n2-log1-frack2n2/512071#512071), I wanted to find a limit in closed form as known numbers but I could not find a way to express it.

$$\alpha=\lim_{n\to\infty}[(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n\ln(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2})})-\frac{{n \pi}^2}{6}]$$

$$\ln (x+1)=\frac{x}{1} -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4}+ ....=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{x^k}{k}$$
$$\frac{1}{n\ln(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2})}=\frac{1}{n(\frac{x^2}{n^2} - \frac{x^4}{2n^4} + \frac{x^6}{3n^6}+ \cdots)}=\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{n}- \frac{x^4}{2n^3} + \frac{x^6}{3n^5}+ \cdots}=\frac{n}{x^2}(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{x^2}{2n^2} + \frac{x^4}{3n^4}+ \cdots)}=\frac{n}{x^2}.({1 + \frac{x^2}{2n^2} - \frac{x^4}{12n^4}+ \cdots)}$$

$$\alpha=\lim_{n\to\infty}[(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n\ln(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2})})-\frac{{n \pi}^2}{6}]=\lim_{n\to\infty}[(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{k^2}.(1 + \frac{k^2}{2n^2} - \frac{k^4}{12n^4}+ \cdots) )-\frac{{n \pi}^2}{6}]=\lim_{n\to\infty}[(n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^n1 - \frac{1}{12n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2+ \cdots) -\frac{{n \pi}^2}{6}]= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{36}+ \cdots$$

The results from above we can express the requested number as

$$\alpha=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2k-1} \frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^k}{{dx}^k}(\frac{x}{\ln(1+x)})|_{x=0}$$

maybe that way can help to see the number in closed form

Thanks for answers

EDIT: @user8268 noticed good point.Maybe we can find the result via integral variable change. I want to share the transform from sum into integral representation.

We know that
$$\frac{{\pi}^2}{6}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}$$

Thus we can write that
$$\alpha=\lim_{n\to\infty}[(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n\ln(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2})})-n\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}]$$

$$\alpha=\lim_{n\to\infty}[(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{\ln(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2})})-\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{\frac{k^2}{n^2}})]$$

$$\alpha=\lim_{n\to\infty}[\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{\ln(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2})}-\frac{1}{\frac{k^2}{n^2}})]$$

We can write a  sum as integral because we know a formula that 
$$\int _0^x {f(t) dt}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n f(\frac{kx}{n})$$

Thus
$$\alpha=\int _0^1 {(\frac{1}{\ln(1+t^2)}-\frac{1}{t^2}) dt}$$
Now I can focus on the variable change and try to evaluate the integral as known closed form numbers such as $\ln2, e,\gamma$,  $\pi$ , $\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})$ etc (or their combinations if it is possible )

Comment: you get $\alpha=\int_0^1(1/\log(1+t^2)-1/t^2)dt$, but I'm not sure if it's a "closed form"

Comment: Look at the [formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327416/solve-the-sequence-u-n-1-fracu-1n-fracu-2n-1-ldots-frac/328401#328401) for the $n$th derivative in my answer. Will you be interested in one similar to it?

Comment: The numerical integration leads to $\alpha = 0.478086$. Is that of any help ?